# From a Modal Controller to a Detail VC of a Master VC, with proper back button (Contacts.app style)

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller

I'm currently implementing an app really close to the native `Contacts app`. The app consists of:

- A Master View listing items
- A Detail View showing the selected item details
- An `add` button to add an item which:

  - Allows to take a picture if the camera is available then go to the input view (a form basically). The camera is presented **modally**.
  - Directly goes to the input view (the form) is no camera or no authorization. The input view is presented **modally**.

**The QUESTION**

When the user presses the `OK` button after filling the form in the Input View, how can I **jump to the Detail View, with the Back Button of the Detail View pointing towards the Master Vie**w (and not the Input View where the user comes from) ?

This is exactly the behavior of the native Contacts app, when you add a contact and press OK, you land on the Detail View with the back button leading to the list of contacts.

Here is how my storyboard looks like:
[image]

I searched a lot for a solution, but nothing good sor far...

Thank you in advance for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`MasterViewController` is a `NavigationController`.

`DetailViewController` is a `ChildViewController` of `MasterViewController`

`CreationViewController` is presented modally from `MasterViewController`

You need to provide delegate for the `MasterViewController` to know the `CreationViewController` have finished the creation flow and the created info. Then you `dismiss` the `CreationViewController` in `MasterViewController`. Finally, you `push` `DetailViewController` with the created info.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. Can you also tell me how to have the same animation (a sort of fade) as the Contacts app? Because when I dismiss the modal VC, I get the reverse modal animation.

Comment: I think you can have a look at `modaltransitionstyle` https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621388-modaltransitionstyle?language=objc

Comment: Yes it works for modal transition, but since in the same time I'm pushing the Detail View, I do not get the same effect as the Contacts app :/

Comment: You can try push the Detail View with no animation beforehand, then dismiss the Modal VC with fade animation.

Comment: Thank you, that was it. I did not know I could push a view before dismissing the modal one !